# R function that counts rows where conditions are met

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column that counts each column where criteria are met. That is because I want to summarize the number of correct answers by each participant in my master thesis. I am really new to R and in desperate need for help, even on easy tasks.

**For Example:**

(Participant,    Task1,     Task2,     Task3;   COUNT)

1                  4         8         1    ;   **1**|

2                  3         8         7    ;   **1**|

3                  1         3         4    ;   **2**|

4                  5         6         4    ;   **1**|

5                  1         8         4    ;   **3**

The column COUNT should count all correct answers of the rows Task1-Task3. If the correct answers are (1, 8, 4), the COUNT row should result in the numbers shown in the example above.

Can anybody tell me how to create such a variable?

Really appreciated, thanks
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` by making the vector `c(1, 8, 4)` length same as the 'Task' columns length and do a `==`, and get the `rowSums`

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(df1), 'Task')
df1$COUNT <-   rowSums(df1[i1] ==  c(1, 8, 4)[col(df1[i1])])
df1$COUNT
#[1] 1 1 2 1 3
```

Or with `sweep`

```
rowSums(sweep(df1[i1], 2, c(1, 8, 4), `==`))
```

Or another option is `apply`

```
df1$COUNT <- apply(df1[i1], 1, function(x) sum(x == c(1, 8, 4)))
```

NOTE: None of the solutions require any external package

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Participant = 1:5, Task1 = c(4, 3, 1, 5, 1),
   Task2 = c(8, 8, 3, 6, 8), Task3 = c(1, 7, 4, 4, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap_int` from `purrr` to count number of correct answers.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(COUNT = purrr::pmap_int(select(., starts_with('Task')), 
                               ~sum(c(...) == c(1, 8, 4))))


#  Participant Task1 Task2 Task3 COUNT
#1           1     4     8     1     1
#2           2     3     8     7     1
#3           3     1     3     4     2
#4           4     5     6     4     1
#5           5     1     8     4     3
```

---

Another option is to get data in long format, calculate the number of correct answers for each `Participant` and join the data back.

```
df1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Task')) %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  summarise(COUNT = sum(value == c(1, 8, 4))) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = 'Participant')
```